# Unity3d Ragdoll Stuck in box collider

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, ragdoll

I created a ragdoll for bike racing in Unity3d but when bike crashes and the ragdoll start dragging its hand stucks in the box colliders that are applied on sides i tried different methods, changed collision modes from Discrete to Continuous to solve this problem but failed. I attached the screen shot in which it is clearly visible. Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in Advance.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather write this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to comment.

Did you try to lower the 'FixedTimestep' to make the physics calcultations more accurate?

See http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-TimeManager.html

Another thing you could try is to lower the 'Min Penetration For Penalty' to reduce the risk of colliders breaking throug other colliders. See http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-PhysicsManager.html

Comment: I tried these two methods but the problem still exists. Thanks for your answer.